# Passing variables outwith a function in JavaScript - My understanding of vars and scopes

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Okay so I've looked on YouTube, read tutorials and blog posts, what in lords name am I missing?

I am populating the following via firebase auth

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    console.log(uid); // <---- This works
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});

console.log(uid); // <---- This doesn't
```

Now upon using console.log() and passing the variables to it, the correct outputs are received however I can't use the variables outwith that function.

I've looked and looked and the word "var" keeps re-appearing commonly attached to the word "global"
I tried declaring the variables outwith the function i.e.

```
 uid = user.uid;
```

and

```
var uid;
```

declared above the function and the exact same result.

Can someone point out what very obvious thing I'm missing, I'm not asking for code to be re-written or anything of the sort! Just an explanation of the key concept I'm failing to grasp here.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe some explanations from javascript.info can help you. You might check our https://javascript.info/var (and even https://javascript.info/closure) to start.

Comment: Basically, variables declared in inner scopes are not available in outer scopes. I think using `var` can do something weird that makes the variable declaration get 'hoisted' to the global scope. I wouldn't recommend using `var` without a good reason. Prefer `const` or `let`. (And in non-strict mode, you can declare global variables, ie create new properties of the `window` object, with no keyword at all. I wouldn't recommend this either.)

Comment: Thank you @Cat! While I haven't specifically fixed my problem, I now understand the difference in scopes and relatively grasped when to use the appropriate declaration typed :)

I just need to work out how to get the data in those variables out of the function, I'm seeing some things using arrays and returns but the creates little conflicts with firebase, thanks again though! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Sigh why do you need to access uid outside?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
let uid = "";
let displayName = "";
let email = "";

const user = await auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => user ? user : null);

if (user) {
   uid = user.uid;
   displayName = user.displayName;
   email = user.email;
}

console.log(uid);
```

Comment: I tried this and received "undefined" followed by an async error, I tagged in async which got rid of the error but still resulted in "undefined". Thank you for trying though, I see your thought process! :)

Comment: It's a pretty incomplete code as is.
Could you kindly expand on what is returned as undefined?

Comment: The last piece of your code console.log(uid); @iamleftclick. However I have solved my problem, I was incorrectly using firebase and its provided functions, what I was trying to isn't actually possible without a specific firebase function, thank you again though for the efforts!